# Is there a way to set a return address for a function in C

Tags: c, return, memory-address

so I know that the `__builtin_return_address(0)` will show what the return address is, but I was wondering if there was a way to set it manually. Does C or any other programming language support this kind of functionality? I've tried searching online for it but I couldn't find much.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to search for coroutines but I don't believe they are well supported.

Comment: C does not support this, at least not in a standard way. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: C standard doesn't specify anything related to stack, so there's no way to know the return value

Comment: How would you determine a working return address to patch it?

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to variably set the return address in assembler, so I don't see how it would make sense in C either.

Comment: @Lundin that's a good point, even for coroutines it isn't done by changing the return address; they just change the stack pointer and execute a jump, essentially. Rewriting the return address and executing `ret` is just a weird indirect jump anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it is complicated. You need to use *setjmp* and *longjmp* and you need to take care what happens at your return point, otherwise you create an infinity loop.

PS keep care, if you *longjmp* into another function than `main()`, you can't use its return type, but have either to use the `exit()` function of *stdlib.h* or to *longjmp* to another valid position

PPS another interesting feature, which you also might like are the so called "Labels as Values": https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf env_a, env_b;

typedef enum _returntype{
    RETURN_A,
    RETURN_B
} RETURNTYPE;

void function(RETURNTYPE r){
    switch(r){
        case RETURN_A :
            longjmp(env_a, 1);
        case RETURN_B :
            longjmp(env_b, 1);
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char character = 'A';
       
    if(setjmp(env_a) != 0){
        printf("returned from env_a, character=%c\n", character);
        goto END;
    }
    
    character = 'B';
    
    if(setjmp(env_b) != 0){
        printf("returned from env_b, character=%c\n", character);
        goto END;
    }
    
    function(RETURN_A); /* or you might use function(RETURN_B); */
    
    END:
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```